# Trajectory of hitting stump by swinging the ball

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, everyday-life, projectile

If we want to hit a target by a stone or missile we have to consider and calculate the interaction of the surroundings with the thrown object precisely. Can you show a mathematical model or trajectory how a bowler hit the stumps by swinging or reverse swinging the ball?

Comment: The cricket term “swing” may not be known to a general audience, I’d consider adding a definition

Comment: I don’t understand “bowler” and “stumps” either. What are they?

Comment: The bowler is the person launching the ball and the stumps are the target. I believe “swing” is the same as spin, but I’m not 100% certain so haven’t edited the question myself.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_bowling

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be done with a mathematical model, because swing bowling (quite distinct from spin, btw) depends on the layer of turbulence adhering to the edge of the ball, and we cannot accurately give a mathematical model of turbulence. However, the basic physical principles can be explained.

First, consider golf balls. Golf balls are dimpled because it was found that old balls flew further than smooth new balls. The reason is that a thin layer of turbulence acts like a lubricant, reducing the resistance to motion through the air caused by viscosity.

If the dimples are too deep, greater turbulence reverses the effect, and causes greater drag.

Swing bowling depends on creating a layer of turbulence on one side of the ball, and a lesser layer on the other side. This is determined by the position of the seam (which a clever bowler causes to changes during the flight), and is enhanced by having a worn ball with one side rough and the other smooth. Hence cricketers will polish one side of the ball to increase the amount it swings.

Reverse swing can be generated by a bowler who is fast enough. This needs an old ball, with greater turbulence. In this case the side with more turbulence drags on the ball, causing the ball to swing in the reverse direction.

A truly great bowler can seam the ball as well as swing it. A seamer relies on bouncing the ball on the seam, so that the bounce is not straight. The West Indian great, Malcolm Marshal, was the ultimate exponent, regularly sending down unplayable deliveries by swinging it one way, bouncing it the other way, and then swinging it back in the original direction.

He may also be able to control when the ball swings. It may fly straight and then swing late, with the batsman already committed to a false shot.

By the way, the bowler is not always trying to hit the stumps. He is more likely trying to force the batsman to play by making him think it might hit the stumps, and then to swing it away so that it hits the edge of the bat and sends a catch to slip (bowlers who swing the ball too far can get fewer wickets because the batsman misses completely). Other times he may be trying to make the batsman wallop what he thinks is an easy ball, and again, send up a catch. He will employ numerous other tricks. He may send down a "yorker" designed to bounce under the position of the bat, or a "slower ball", causing the batsman to mistime his shot, or simply scare the living daylights out of him with a bouncer, requiring either evasive action to avoid bodily injury, or a hook which if not timed perfectly is also likely to lead to a catch. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Providing “swing” refers to spinning of the ball, the explanation you are looking for is the [Magnus effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect). A spinning object moving through a fluid (in this case a ball moving through air) will deviate from a parabolic path: a ball spinning clockwise as viewed by the bowler will curve to the right, and the converse for an anticlockwise spin.

There is also an additional effect due to friction between the spinning ball and the ground when it bounces, again causing its path to deviate.

Experienced bowlers are able to judge the magnitude of these caused by the spin so the ball hits the desired target.